# C character pointers

Tags: c, pointers, character

So I have a struct in C

```
struct LData {
    char* name;
    int age;
    int sex; /* 0 = male, 1 = female */
};
```

Thats created with

```
struct LData *create_data(char *name, int age, int sex) {
    struct LData *data;

    data = malloc(sizeof(struct LData));
    data->name = name;
    data->age = age;
    data->sex = sex;

return data;
}
```

And I try and print this information using

```
void print_data(struct LData *data) {
    char *sex;

    if (data->sex == 0) {
        sex = "male";
    } else {sex = "female";}
    printf("%c-%d-%c",data->name, data->age, *sex);
}
```

But I keep getting this formating error:

```
listdata.c: In function _print_data_:
listdata.c:52:2: warning: format _%c_ expects argument of type _int_, but argument 2 has type      _char *_ [-Wformat=]
printf("%c-%d-%c",data->name, data->age, *sex);
```

I know something is messed up with my *name pointer, but I can't quite pin point it.

Comment: `%c` is for a single character.  You could use `%s` for a pointer to a character array...

Comment: `name` is a *string*, so...

Comment: Wow so dumb... did not realize %c for single char and %s for string, sorry java programmer new to C

Answer (score 2):

For a string (pointer to char) you need `%s` instead of `%c`.

Comment: Although you surely want to express the right thing: A "*pointer to char*" **is not** "*a string*"!

Comment: @alk I didn't say they are *the same*. The pointer in this case should point to a character in a null-terminated string.